# Scala JAXB 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions

Tags: xml, scala, jaxb, annotations

I have two Scala case classes, which have JAXB annotations.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso({ Array(classOf[Element]) })
case class Config(
    @(XmlElement @field) name: String,
    @(XmlElement @field) reelCount: Int,
    @(XmlElement @field) slots: Int,
    @(XmlElementWrapper @field)@(XmlAnyElement @field) elements: List[Element]) {
    private def this() = this("", 0, 0, new ArrayList())
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
case class Element(
    @(XmlAttribute @field)@(XmlID @field) id: Int,
    @(XmlElement @field) name: String,
    @(XmlElement @field) imgPath: String) {
    private def this() = this(0, "", "")
}
```

The marshalling works, when I remove the `@(XmlID @field)` annotation from the first attribute of the Element. When I annotate it with the xml id field, I get following exception:

```
[IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions]
```

It should work in Java with this 2 annotations, but no idea what I'm doing wrong in Scala. Any ideas? Or maybe some workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) reference implementation only allows the `@XmlID` annotation on fields/properties on type `String`.  This is why you are getting an `IllegalAnnotationsException` on your field of type `Int`.